# Python requests post JSON raw data in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, itemupdated, python

I want to update some property in a SharePoint ListItem.

I'm using this code:

```
body = '{"__metadata": {"type": "SP.Data.Documentos_x0020_compartidosItem"}, "Tarea": "TP 15"}'
```

```
header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearer + '', 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 'X-HTTP-Method':'MERGE','content-type': 'application/json', 'IF-MATCH'
: '*'}
```

and I make this call:

```
requests.post("https://[sharepoint URL]/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documentos')/items(232)",json=body,headers=header).json()
```

but I get always the same answer:

```
{'error': {'code': '-1, '
                   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException',
           'message': {'lang': 'es-ES',
                       'value': "Se encontró un nodo 'PrimitiveValue' "
                                'inesperado al leer del lector JSON. Se '
                                "esperaba un nodo 'StartObject'."}}}
```

Value translation: "An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. It was expected a 'Startobject' node"

Could anyone give me any clue about this issue?

Previously I built similar request on Postman and it worked succesffully:
[image]

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: What is the column Type of Tarea?
Can you please share the screenshot of your list column types?

Comment: For sure!
it's just a customized column
Here you have a screenshot:
https://ibb.co/1T1X5Kx

Comment: Is Tarea or Zone any of them are lookup columns?

Comment: I'm not sure enough what you mean with "lookup columns". Sorry, my knowledge about SharePoint is pretty elemental. For me they are either customized or personal columns. How could I confirm that feature?

I must say I haven't found any problem to update those customized columns from Postman

Comment: Kindly share the screenshot of the list settings under which columns are listed.

Comment: You can reach to list settings by clicking on the gear icon available at the right top corner of the page

Comment: I think those Columns are "Select a value" kind
https://ibb.co/vJFhZ2N

Comment: I'm afraid we are using Spanish layout
https://ibb.co/HPjLrcb

Comment: I don't want to be rude but I must insist that Postman is able to perform that task.

I have the problem when I try to translate the Postman request on Python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104126/discussion-between-miguel-barbero-real-and-litt-spector).

Answer (score 0):

You have your `Accept` set this way, but in order to POST/PUT/PATCH metadata in that format, your `content-type` also needs to be set to `'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'`.

Comment: Thanks willman

I have tried your suggestion but the answer is the same.

https://ibb.co/MCRQkk5